# Atomic fence concurrency between Goroutines and C threads - what are the semantics?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, cgo, atomic

I'm wondering if it is possible to coordinate atomic operation concurrency between goroutines and C threads explicitly.

The use case here involves an audio processing library in C, which creates an OS thread, and periodically calls a user-supplied callback to retrieve audio data.  This must happen in almost real-time, so I don't want to incur the overhead of cgo calls, stack swaps, and Go-land concurrency.  A ring buffer can solve this problem in general, where one thread writes to the buffer, another reads, and synchronization is performed with memory fences.

However, it appears that currently the memory semantics of atomic operations in Go is left completely undefined in the docs, and therefore utterly useless for this purpose, and probably many others.... (https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/ unhelpfully just says "atomic", see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5045)

But - it has to work *in some way*, even if that's not documented.  How?

PLEASE NOTE I am not asking about solutions to the problem I describe, however.  I am not asking if ring buffers are the correct choice, or if I should "communicate by sharing" or whatever.  I am asking after the currently implemented memory order semantics of atomic operations in Go (say, the latest release version - 1.16.5 for concreteness).

In particular, here is a sample program which sets up a similar situation to what occurs in my actual use case:

```
package main

/*

   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <malloc.h>

   typedef struct {
      int fence_0;
      char *data;
   } shared_data;

   shared_data *make_shared_data() {
      shared_data *sd = calloc(sizeof(shared_data), 1);
      sd->data = calloc(1024,1);
      sd->data[0] = 17;
      return sd;
   }

   void *get_shared_data_ptr(shared_data *sd) {
      return sd->data;
   }

   int read_data_in_pthread(shared_data *sd) {
      int l;
      __atomic_load(&sd->fence_0, &l, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
      if (l < 2) return 0;
      return sd->data[0] + sd->data[1023]; 
   }

*/
import "C"
import (
   "fmt"
   "runtime"
   "reflect"
   "unsafe"
   "sync/atomic"
)

func main() {

   // Prevent thread/cache switching (to avoid asking a third, unimportant question and allow the below "naughty")
   runtime.LockOSThread()

   // Allocate a C-owned structure.
   csd := C.make_shared_data()

   // This is just an expedient for the sake of this example, I'm aware it's naughty/bad, etc.
   ptr := (*byte)(C.get_shared_data_ptr(csd))
   arrptr := &reflect.SliceHeader{Data: uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ptr)), Len: 1024, Cap: 1024}
   arr := *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(arrptr))

   fmt.Printf("%d\n", arr[0])
   done := make(chan bool)

   // Repeatedly execute a reader function in a cgo thread which will output zero if first fence is not 2
   // and output the sum of the first and last data points if it is.
   go func(){
         var s uint8
         s = 0
         for s == 0 {
            s = uint8(C.read_data_in_pthread(csd))
         }
         fmt.Printf("finished: %d\n", s)
         done <- true
      }()

   go func(){
         atomic.StoreInt32((*int32)(&csd.fence_0), 1)
         for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
            arr[i] = 255
         }
         atomic.StoreInt32((*int32)(&csd.fence_0), 2)
   }()

   <-done
}
```

The question is:  (a) Can the output of this program ever be `17`?   (b) IF not, must the output of this program always be `254`, or might it be `255`?

If the Go atomic stores work with a memory model similar to gcc's ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, the memory fence is sequential, and we'll always see `254`.  This would seem to be a sensible default.  But, is it necessarily true?

If not, my program will be non-portable and produce errors. So, I'd like to know for sure.

(Yes, I know the test case above is definitely entirely non-portable / only runs on GNU/Linux... the actual library in question is in fact portable.)

Comment: First some clarification, atomic operations do not serialize access, they merely make concurrent access safe. This means they do not provide synchronization for goroutines.

Comment: I'm not suite sure how to actually answer your question, as the `atomic` package will cause the compiler to emit the necessary instructions for atomic operations on your architecture, which seems to be what you want. Are you asking if there is some possibility that gcc's `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE` is not compatible with the instructions used by the Go compiler? (the mailing list is probably a better place to ask implementation details like this, as the go developers are the most familiar with the compiler implementation)

Comment: Atomic operations are absolutely used for low-level synchronization, it's a mainstay of concurrent programming, usually when locking is too expensive.  And  I'm literally asking something very specific about the output of precisely given code there!   That said, gcc's code doesn't in any way have to be "compatible", the two operations occur in different threads with different memory cache.  I'm asking about the cache semantics of the Go side - the gcc side is well-defined in the gcc docs. In a correct concurrency implementation, they'd work together - but I'm only asking about the Go side.

Comment: You are not asking about a specific thing, you've asked multiple questions and now you're brought up caches which are mostly irrelevant to the discussion ([Myths Programmers Believe about CPU Caches](https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/)). It still reads to me like you're asking "is atomic really atomic?", but perhaps you can get a more nuanced answer from one of the developers themselves.

Comment: The only question I'm asking is "What is the semantically correct output of my program".  (a), or (b), or <something else>.   There is no other question.  Your link has nothing to do with my question.   The rest of the text in the question above is simply expository.   I'm not asking if those writes are "actually atomic" - this is not a well-defined ask and can mean many finer-grained things - my program depends on which of those finer-grained things was actually implemented.  Make sense?

Comment: Interfacing with other languages falls outside the "happens-before" semantics of the [Go memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem). So the compiler is forced to ensure it doesn't reorder memory accesses beyond the sync point, since it can't "see" past the language boundary, and must issue proper fences for the CPU. The same applies to the [C side](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model) of the code, BTW.

Comment: Ok, cool.  That implies that the resulting memory order is sequential, right?   We should always get `254`.    If you know that for sure, that's an answer and I'll accept it if you post.  (also means I can actually use Go for this project, bonus....)   Can you say anything additional or supporting about how `sync/atomic` is actually implemented?  (Like, it might actually just call gcc's __atomic_store() or whatever?  What about other compilers like clang, etc?)

Comment: (Does the compiler always fence, or does it depend on if C or Go "owns" the memory, as it does for pointer passing?   ie. would it use some more relaxed semantics if it were merely two goroutines?)

Comment: As I explain above, in this case the overhead of explicit locking is unsuitable (because it incurs a millisecond or so context switch and stack swap in the middle of realtime audio processing with frames on that order).   I've been writing concurrent software for 20+ years, I'm familiar with the fact that this paradigm is a huge PITA.  I'm just trying to make this work in Go, because I really think it's well suited for this in lots of other ways.  The link isn't really relevant, but hanks for the C&P warning, though (it's generally good advice).

Answer (score 2):

There's a sort of impedance mismatch, as it were, between the [Go memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) and the (multiple) memory models available in C and C++ (see [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) on C memory order options, and note that [C++ has a more nuanced view than C11 did, beginning in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)).  This can, at least in theory, make for some big headaches for implementors: calls in and out of C code, via cgo, might need to do heavy-duty CPU sync if, e.g., the Go system uses some sort of total or partial store order model and the C system uses a relaxed memory model.

In practice, each implementation will strive to use the same kinds of synchronizations for atomic-load-32 and atomic-store-32, for instance.  But:

> The use case here involves an audio processing library in C, which creates an OS thread, and periodically calls a user-supplied callback to retrieve audio data. This must happen in almost real-time, so I don't want to incur the overhead of cgo calls, stack swaps, and Go-land concurrency. A ring buffer can solve this problem in general, where one thread writes to the buffer, another reads, and synchronization is performed with memory fences.
>
> [snip]
>
> But - it has to work in some way, even if that's not documented. How?

You're going to have to look at each implementation, one at a time, because the "how" could—at least potentially—be different each time.  So find out what your systems use on their PowerPC implementations, find out what your systems use on their ARM implementations, and so on.  You'll want to have your low level Go routines be implementation-specific, chosen to work with your low-level C routines.

Answer (score 1):

The language itself doesn't define any atomic operations. The `sync/atomic` package, however, does. The issue you link is prefixed "doc:", meaning that they're only debating how to improve the documentation surrounding `atomic`'s interaction with the Go memory model. The package still works. The operations in it are atomic as described. Any known exceptions are listed in the "Bugs" section: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#pkg-note-BUG

Comment: Yes, the question is obviously about `sync/atomic`.   It definitely works with some semantics, sure.   I'm asking /what those semantics are/, since they are undocumented.  If I hand you a function `frob(n int)`, it definitely works.  You don't know what it does tho, whoops.   Here, we know that store/load is atomic, but we don't know about cache / memory model semantics.   An answer to my question will resolve the issue of the behavior of the sample code, which is constructed to depend on those semantics.  It doesn't depend on if the writes are actually atomic or not.   This is not an answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with the usual meaning of "atomic operation?" Go and standard library never specify anything nearly as low level as CPU cache. This is the kind of thing you'd consult the CPU spec for.

Comment: Perhaps the reason why it seems like a non-answer, is because you're asking how the language defines something that it doesn't define.

Comment: I'm asking about the behavior of a specific MCVE I put in the question, with an explicit multiple choice question about it.  One possible answer is "the behavior is undefined" - that would be my (a) above.   If you're not familiar with how atomic operations are used to synchronize between threads on multicache / multicore systems in concurrent programming, it's OK to just take a pass on this one instead of telling me what you think my terms mean or that my question is somehow ill-posed.  It isn't.

Comment: (In general, the Go docs are far from "sharp" - it's often the case that they're just incomplete or under construction - as is literally the case here, evidenced by the issue I linked.  So, we cannot conclude that the absence of assertion to the contrary means undefined behavior.)

Comment: Your linked issue as evidence is more about defining  "happens before" semantics, and not about what "atomic" actually means, and that is not relevant to the use case you present here.

Comment: I'm not putting an intro-to-cache-coherency in the comment section here, but those two things are definitely intimately related.  (They're almost the same thing, in fact.)   Again, if the question seems weirdly posed - (a), (b), or something else as the output of that very well defined code in the question is the answer I'm looking for. There is definitely an answer to that question.  If you don't know it (I don't see how anyone who hasn't read the Go runtime source could), again, it's OK to just take a pass.

Comment: Your question mentions portability, and you haven't specified the particular platforms you're targeting, so we might assume that you're asking about how Go defines this behavior generally. In the general case, the answer is that it's undefined. Even if some people have discussed it before, that doesn't mean that ever will be or should be part of the spec.

Comment: There is nothing even close to a "spec", or this question would not exist.   There is some documentation of the implementation.  Putting the answer into the documentation  is literally slated into a future Go release.  They will put something there, it definitely behaves a certain way currently, because it is implemented.  So, what will they put there?  How is it implemented?    Please stop the senseless spam debate in the comments if the question is valid or not, now.   You're just scrolling and adding noise to last-word.  We can take it to a side discussion if you like.

Comment: Where is it slated for future release? Maybe that reference could be part of a better answer to this question. I didn't mean to invalidate your question, but I think we both just had a different intent in the question vs answer. If it's not the answer you're looking for, that is ok, but I don't think I should be insulted for trying